# Simplification of trigonometric expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I would like to automate the simplification of certain trigonometric expressions, such as

```
Cos[1/2 q^(-1-k) z]^q^(1+k) Cos[(q^-k z)/2]^-q^k Sin[1/2 q^(-1-k) z]^-q^(1+k) Sin[(q^-k z)/2]^q^k
```

However, using many trigonometric simplification functions in Mathematica does not yield the expected transformation, such as `TrigReduce`, `PowerExpand`..., which at first glance seems elementary. I imagine this might be due to powers, but when numerical values are used, the desired simplification is achieved.

How could this be done?

Comment: Since you mention it works with numerical values, I wonder if it might work if you include assumptions like `q>0&&k>0&&Element[z,Reals]`, all the stuff that you think is obvious to you and Mathematica isn't reading your mind. You can add assumptions to Simplify or use `Assuming` around a block, etc. You might be surprised to learn that MMA assumes everything is Complex and trig functions can be very odd with complex arguments. Try giving it all the hints that you assume and see whether it works or not and then please report back. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not say what you expect the simplification to be. If you mean you wan to convert the input to 2 tans, you can make a rule

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
e1 = Cos[1/2  q^(-1 - k)  z]^
   q^(1 + k)  Cos[(q^-k  z)/2]^-q^k  Sin[
    1/2  q^(-1 - k)  z]^-q^(1 + k)  Sin[(q^-k  z)/2]^q^k
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now

```
rep1 = Sin[any_]^b_*Cos[any_]^(-b_) :> Tan[any]^b;
rep2 = Sin[any_]^(-b_)*Cos[any_]^(b_) :> 1/(Tan[any]^b);
e1 /. rep1 /. rep2
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

These two rules can be combined to one if needed.

Comment: "Thanks @Nasser, but this result doesn't automate other trigonometric functions completely, although it is a good result for some cases."

Comment: I have prove {Assuming[Element[{k,n,q},Integers]&&k>0&&n>0&&q>0&&Element[z,Reals],Cos[1/2 q^(-1-k) z]^q^(1+k) Cos[(q^-k z)/2]^-q^k Sin[1/2 q^(-1-k) z]^-q^(1+k) Sin[(q^-k z)/2]^q^k]//PowerExpand//TrigReduce//FullSimplify} but do not work

Comment: @Sheparcapea if Simplify and friends do not work, the other option is to make your own transformation rules based on patterns. This is the power of symbolic computation.